# Regexp_extract from URL

Tags: regex, google-bigquery, regex-group

The URL is

```
https://example.com/fid=&ti_gen=yolobleh&er_mess=beatle&
```

I am looking to extract `yolobleh` from the URL.

I can get `ti_gen=yolobleh` using the following syntax but I am only looking to extract `yolobleh`:

```sql
regexp_extract(url,r'ti_gen=[^&]+')
```

Answer (score 1):

Since [`REGEXP_EXTRACT`](https://support.google.com/looker-studio/answer/7050487?hl=en) returns the captured value if the regex contains a capturing group, you just need to enclose `[^&]+` part in the expression with parentheses:

```
regexp_extract(url,r'ti_gen=([^&]+)')
```